# Accessing a vector which is a value in a map to run the equality operator on it with another vector

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, stl

I have a vector that is made up of maps which have the following type definition:

`std::map< int, std::vector<int> >`

Thus, the definition of the vector itself is:

`std::vector< std::map< int, std::vector<int> > >`

Now I am creating a vector of integers and inserting it in a map with an integer key and adding the map itself to the outer vector:

```
    std::map<int, std::vector<int> > vDescriptorAtom;
    vDescriptorAtom.insert( std::make_pair(498, vListOfIds) );
    messageDescriptorVector.push_back( vDescriptorAtom );
```

Where vListOfIds itself is a vector of integers.

At a later stage I want to extract the inner vector and compare with another vector that I possess. I was under the impression that I can easily use the `==` operator between the two vectors to do the comparison. But I am having some trouble doing this.

I tried:

```
               for ( int i = 0 ; i <= messageDescriptorVector.size(); i++ )
                {    
                    if ( current_tag_stack == (messageDescriptorVector.at(i))->second )
                    {
                        vFoundMatchingDescriptor = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Note that current_tag_stack  has the following definition:

```
std::vector<int> current_tag_stack;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
base operand of â->â has non-pointer type âstd::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >â
```

What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

As suggested by a comment, I tried to access the vector that I have stored inside the map as: `messageDescriptorVector.at(i).second` but it is giving me this error: `âclass std::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >â has no member named âsecondâ`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear on that. Use `.`, not `->`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nope, that did not work. It just threw this error: ` âclass std::map<int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > > >â has no member named âsecondâ
`

Comment: For God's sake use typedefs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`messageDescriptorVector.at(i)` is a map. You have to obtain an element of that map, in order to get it's `second` and compare it with your reference vector. So you need one more level of iteration.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < messageDescriptorVector.size(); i++ )
{
  auto& m = messageDescriptorVector.at(i); // m is a map<int, vector<int>>

  for (auto& p : m) // p is a ref to pair<int, vector<int>>
  {
    if ( current_tag_stack == p.second )
    {
      // do something ....
```

or just

```
for (auto& m : messageDescriptorVector)
{
  for (auto& p : m)
  {
    if ( current_tag_stack == p.second )
    {
      // do something ....
```

Comment: `auto m& = messageDescriptorVector.at(i); // m is a map<int, vector<int>>` Wait so how does auto m& works? shouldn't ampersand & be before variable name?

Comment: @VG Yes indeed, that was a typo, now fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for taking care of it but only one typo is fixed ^^ The other is still out there.

Comment: @VG Fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Aside of issue that you are trying to accessing member second on a map, I would recommend to use typedefs in your code. It will not only simplify your code, but will help to change data structure if necessary. In your case all of this definitions all around your code:

```
std::map< int, std::vector<int> >
std::vector< std::map< int, std::vector<int> > >
std::map<int, std::vector<int> > vDescriptorAtom;
std::vector<int> current_tag_stack;
```

Compare it with:

```
typedef std::vector<int> tag_stack;
typedef std::map<int,tag_stack> tag_stack_map;

tag_stack_map vDescriptorAtom;
tag_stack current_tag_stack;
```

And imagine one day you would need to change your tag_stack from std::vector to something else. Where it will be easier?

Answer (score 1):

function at() returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, so you should write:

```
(messageDescriptorVector.at(i)).second
```

I preferred write this code like:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> vDescriptorAtom;
std::vector<std::map<int, std::vector<int>>> messageDescriptorVector;

vDescriptorAtom[498] = vListOfIds;
messageDescriptorVector.push_back( vDescriptorAtom );

// do something

for(auto& maps : messageDescriptorVector)
    for(auto& pairs : maps)
        if (current_tag_stack == pairs.second)
            // do something
```